# How to use cpulimit on ALL cron jobs?

Tags: server, cron, cpu-load, cpu, amazon-ec2

Using Ubuntu Server an AWS micro box, so *if the cpu utilization spikes* AWS will virtually kill the CPU for the box (for about 30 sec).

`nice` doesn't solve the problem, but `cpulimit` does (I use it in my own cpu intensive cron jobs).

Some system default cron jobs are triggering the AWS cpu limiter.

There are about 15 default cron job scripts, rather than trying to re-write every one to use cpulimit, is there a way I can use cpulimit to **limit the cpu of all cron jobs** (that would have to *include the sub processes* that are spawned by the various scripts)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like I found the answer to my question, great stuff here: a cpulimit daemon script that works box-wide.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=992706

Answer (score 3):

I realize this was originally asked in 2011,
but nowadays you can achieve a similar result by
[altering `cron.service`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/659267/how-do-i-override-or-configure-systemd-services)
to [limit the CPU and I/O priority](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Scheduling):

```
$ sudo systemctl edit cron.service
# edits go to /etc/systemd/system/cron.service.d/override.conf
```

By default, this also applies to subprocesses spawned by cron.
I use something like this:

```
[Service]
Nice=19
CPUSchedulingPolicy=idle
IOSchedulingClass=idle
```