# How do I override or configure systemd services?

Tags: configuration, services, systemd

Many sysv init scripts used a corresponding file in `/etc/default` to allow the administrator to configure it. Upstart jobs can be modified using `.override` files. How do I override or configure systemd units, now that systemd is the default in Ubuntu?

Comment: Note that when clearing the `ExecStart=` with a blank entry you cannot put a comment after it like: `ExecStart= # Empty line to clear previous entries.` This will be taken as another `ExecStart=` entry and added to the list. PS. I could not add comment to muru's answer because of my low reputation.

Answer (score 386, accepted):

`systemd` units need not obey files in `/etc/default`. `systemd` is easily configurable, but requires that you know the syntax of systemd unit files.

Packages ship unit files typically in `/lib/systemd/system/`. These are *not* to be edited. Instead, `systemd` allows you to override these files by creating appropriate files in `/etc/systemd/system/`.

For a given service `foo`, the package would provide `/lib/systemd/system/foo.service`. You can check its status using `systemctl status foo`, or view its logs using `journalctl -u foo`. To override something in the definition of `foo`, do:

```
sudo systemctl edit foo
```

This creates a directory in `/etc/systemd/system` named after the unit, and an `override.conf` file in that directory (`/etc/systemd/system/foo.service.d/override.conf`). You can add or override settings using this file (or other `.conf` files in `/etc/systemd/system/foo.service.d/`). This is also applicable to non-service units - you could do `systemctl edit foo.mount`, `systemctl edit foo.timer`, etc. It assumes `.service` as the default type if you didn't specify one.

## Overriding command arguments

Take the `getty` service for example. Say I want to have TTY2 autologin to my user (this is not advisable, but just an example). TTY2 is run by the `getty@tty2` service (`tty2` being an instance of the template `/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service`). To do this, I have to modify the `getty@tty2` service.

```
$ systemctl cat getty@tty2
# /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=Getty on %I
Documentation=man:agetty(8) man:systemd-getty-generator(8)
Documentation=http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html
After=systemd-user-sessions.service plymouth-quit-wait.service
After=rc-local.service

# If additional gettys are spawned during boot then we should make
# sure that this is synchronized before getty.target, even though
# getty.target didn't actually pull it in.
Before=getty.target
IgnoreOnIsolate=yes

# On systems without virtual consoles, don't start any getty. Note
# that serial gettys are covered by serial-getty@.service, not this
# unit.
ConditionPathExists=/dev/tty0

[Service]
# the VT is cleared by TTYVTDisallocate
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear %I $TERM
Type=idle
Restart=always
RestartSec=0
UtmpIdentifier=%I
TTYPath=/dev/%I
TTYReset=yes
TTYVHangup=yes
TTYVTDisallocate=yes
KillMode=process
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
SendSIGHUP=yes

# Unset locale for the console getty since the console has problems
# displaying some internationalized messages.
Environment=LANG= LANGUAGE= LC_CTYPE= LC_NUMERIC= LC_TIME= LC_COLLATE= LC_MONETARY= LC_MESSAGES= LC_PAPER= LC_NAME= LC_ADDRESS= LC_TELEPHONE= LC_MEASUREMENT= LC_IDENTIFICATION=

[Install]
WantedBy=getty.target
DefaultInstance=tty1
```

In particular, I have to change the `ExecStart` line, which currently is:

```
$ systemctl cat getty@tty2 | grep Exec     
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear %I $TERM
```

To override this, do:

```
sudo systemctl edit getty@tty2
```

And add:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -a muru --noclear %I $TERM
```

Note that:

1. I had to explicitly clear `ExecStart` before setting it again, as it is an additive setting, similar to other lists like `Environment` (as a whole, not per-variable) and `EnvironmentFile`; and unlike overriding settings like `RestartSec` or `Type`. If I did not clear it, systemd will execute every `ExecStart` line, but you can only have multiple `ExecStart` entries for `Type=oneshot` services.

   - Dependency settings like `Before`, `After`, `Wants`, etc. are also lists, but cannot be cleared using this way. You'll have to override/replace the entire service for that (see below).
2. I had to use the proper section header. In the original file, `ExecStart` is in the `[Service]` section, so my override has to put `ExecStart` in the `[Service]` section as well. Often, having a look at the actual service file using `systemctl cat` will tell you what you need to override and which section it is in.

Usually, if you edit a systemd unit file, for it to take effect, you need to run:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

However, `systemctl edit` automatically does this for you.

Now:

```
$ systemctl cat getty@tty2 | grep Exec
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear %I $TERM
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -a muru --noclear %I $TERM

$ systemctl show getty@tty2 | grep ExecS
ExecStart={ path=/sbin/agetty ; argv[]=/sbin/agetty -a muru --noclear %I $TERM ; ... }
```

And if I do:

```
sudo systemctl restart getty@tty2
```

and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>, presto! I'll be logged into my account on that TTY.

As I said before, `getty@tty2` is an instance of a template. So, what if I wanted to override all instances of that template? That can be done by editing the template itself (removing the instance identifier - in this case `tty2`):

```
systemctl edit getty@
```

## Overriding the environment

A common use case of `/etc/default` files is setting environment variables. Usually, `/etc/default` is a shell script, so you could use shell language constructs in it. With `systemd`, however, this is not the case. You can specify environment variables in two ways:

#### Via a file

Say you have set the environment variables in a file:

```
$ cat /path/to/some/file
FOO=bar
```

Then, you can add to the override:

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/path/to/some/file
```

In particular, if your `/etc/default/foo` contains only assignments and no shell syntax, you could use it as the `EnvironmentFile`.

#### Via `Environment` entries

The above could also be accomplished using the following override:

```
[Service]
Environment=FOO=bar
```

However, this can get tricky with multiple variables, spaces, etc. Have a look at [one of my other answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/614120/158442) for an example of such an instance.

## Variations in editing

### Replacing the existing unit entirely

If you want to make massive changes to the existing unit, such that you're effectively replacing it altogether, you could just do:

```
systemctl edit --full foo
```

### Temporary edits

In the systemd file hierarchy, `/etc` takes precedence over `/run`,  which in turn takes precedence over `/lib`. Everything said so far also applies to using `/run/systemd/system` instead of `/etc/systemd/system`. Typically `/run` is a transient filesystem whose contents are lost on reboot, so if you want to override a unit only until reboot, you can do:

```
systemctl edit --runtime foo
```

However, you cannot use this method to temporarily override something that is already in `/etc` (e.g., snap service files are usually created directly in `/etc/systemd/system`, so you can only override them using files in `/etc/system/system/<snap-service-name>.service.d`).

### Overriding user units

Everything said so far also applies to user units, with `systemctl --user edit`, `systemctl --user daemon-reload`, etc. instead of the corresponding system unit commands. The override files go to `~/.config/systemd/user` instead of `/etc/systemd/system`. If, as an administrator, you want to override user units for all users, then use `/etc/systemd/user` instead.

### Setting specific properties

Many [resource-control properties](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/systemd.resource-control) can be set directly using the `systemctl set-property` command. Example from the manpage:

```
systemctl set-property foobar.service CPUWeight=200 MemoryMax=2G IPAccounting=yes
```

Changes are applied immediately and also persisted to override files. For example, the following command will immediately update the service's resource configuration:

```
systemctl --user set-property foobar.service CPUWeight=200 MemoryMax=2G
```

And also add the following files in the user's home directory (because `--user` makes it a user unit):

```
% head .config/systemd/user.control/cann.service.d/50-*
==> .config/systemd/user.control/cann.service.d/50-CPUWeight.conf <==
# This is a drop-in unit file extension, created via "systemctl set-property"
# or an equivalent operation. Do not edit.
[Service]
CPUWeight=200

==> .config/systemd/user.control/cann.service.d/50-MemoryMax.conf <==
# This is a drop-in unit file extension, created via "systemctl set-property"
# or an equivalent operation. Do not edit.
[Service]
MemoryMax=2147483648
```

## Undoing changes

You can simply remove the corresponding override file, and do `systemctl daemon-reload` to have systemd read the updated unit definition.

You can also *revert* all changes (including ones from `systemctl set-property`):

```
systemctl revert foo
```

## Further Reading

Via this mechanism, it becomes very easy to override `systemd` units, as well as to undo such changes (by simply removing the override file). These are not the only settings which can be modified.

The following links would be useful:

- [Arch Wiki entry on `systemd`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd)
- [*systemd for Administrators*, Part IX: On /etc/sysconfig and /etc/default](http://0pointer.net/blog/projects/on-etc-sysinit.html) (by the lead developer of systemd, Lennart Poettering)
- [The `systemd` manpages](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/), in particular, the manpages of [`systemd.unit`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/systemd.unit.5) and [`systemd.service`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/systemd.service.5)
- [Ubuntu Wiki entry on *Systemd for Upstart users*](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers)

Comment: You have to clear the variable before setting it for services not of the type oneshot. This solved my problem.

Comment: Can anyone point me to where in the systemd docs I can find information on "clearing" the inherited value with `ExecStart=` as shown in this answer?

Comment: @MarkEdington from the `systemd.service(5)` manpage, section on `ExecStart`: "Unless Type= is oneshot, exactly one command must be given. When Type=oneshot is used, zero or more commands may be specified. Commands may be specified by providing multiple command lines in the same directive, or alternatively, this directive may be specified more than once with the same effect. If the empty string is assigned to this option, the list of commands to start is reset, prior assignments of this option will have no effect."

Comment: How to remove override using `systemctl`? I can't just empty file.

Comment: @Orient you can `sudo rm` the override file and then `systemctl daemon-reload`, or you can `systemctl edit` and replace everything in the override with comments. Comments in service files begin with `#`.

Comment: @Orient `systemctl revert foo`

Comment: What is the order of precedence for the three methods (override file, environment file, environment variable)? Ie, for a variable defined in all three, which value will be the effective one?

Comment: If I want to override `ExecStart` by adding/changing some of the command line parameters. How do I do this if I don't know the path to the executable? Do I have to copy the path to the executable or is there some way of preserving it? Also if it is an additive setting, it seems to mean that one should create a "default" command that can have additional settings applied simply be appending more options that override earlier options?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai yes, you have to know the path - which you can get easily enough by using `systemctl cat` or `systemctl show`. It's additive in the sense that multiple instances are added to a list. They don't add to an item in that list.

Comment: is the double `ExecStart` in the override actually necessary, or is that just to hide the previous value in `systemctl show`?

Comment: @xenoterracide depends on if you want to replace the previous value or just add another command to be executed.

Comment: Excellent answer, except one part - it makes you believe you can reset `After`, based on the line "I had to explicitly clear ExecStart before setting it again, as it is an additive setting, similar to After..."
Although it **is** a list/additive setting - as I had to found out from [elsewhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/468067/395448) - you **cannot** reset dependency type settings...

Comment: @KrisztiánSzegi ah, noted, and I have updated the text accordingly. I now see that this is specified explicitly in the last para of Ex 2 In [`man systemd.unit`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#id-1.14.3)

Comment: @muru Nice! Thanks for the time clearing this up!

Comment: What about _top level_ drop-ins? I see them being documented for `systemd` [elsewhere](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#id-1.14.4) but it appears that on Ubuntu (18.04 at least), they don't work as advertised.

Comment: @cueedee I think you need a newer version of systemd for that. The [manpage for 18.04](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man5/systemd.unit.5.html) doesn't mention it, but you can find it in [the manpage for 20.04](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/systemd.unit.5.html)

Comment: @muru - you are correct! It turns out top-level drop-ins need systemd version [244](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v244/man/systemd.unit.xml#L195) or newer. Ubuntu 20 has [245](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/systemd.unit.5.html) while 18 has [237](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/systemd.unit.5.html).