# How to install snap packages behind web proxy

Tags: snap, proxy

I know how to configure APT to use a web proxy. But what about snap?

Comment: There is a reported bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1579652 Please subscribe to check changes on it.

Comment: could you please remove the "16.04" from the title? This topic is relevant for more or less every Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

A system option was added in snap 2.28 to specify the proxy server.

```bsh
$ sudo snap set system proxy.http="http://<proxy_addr>:<proxy_port>"
$ sudo snap set system proxy.https="http://<proxy_addr>:<proxy_port>"
```

[Documentation](https://docs.snapcraft.io/system-options)

Comment: I am using snap/snapd `2.34.2` on Ubuntu 16.04.5 and these options do not work. Had to go with https://askubuntu.com/a/1084862/75760 , changing the systemd settings

Comment: The documentation specifies it works since **snapd 2.28**. Use `snap version` to check your current version.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 18.04, with snap 2.43.3.

Comment: this answer really should be marked as ANSWER, works with Ubuntu1804 and `snap    2.37.4+18.04.1`, jsut a small reminder that if your password has special character, it should be encode (eg: `!` = `%21`)

Comment: For me this worked only without quotation marks (on Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: Note that it is important to type that `http://`! (or `https://` if applicable)

Comment: _error: cannot communicate with server: timeout exceeded while waiting for response_

Answer (score 29):

`snapd` reads `/etc/environment`, so setting the usual proxy environment variables there works. On Ubuntu, that's done automatically for you by Settings → Network → Network proxy, so as long as you restart `snapd` after changing that file you should be set.

Comment: Being more specific, the snapd.service file is located here: /lib/systemd/system/snapd.service

Comment: @darkhole one shouldn't edit `/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service`, but use `systemctl edit snapd.service`. See my answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/659267/how-do-i-override-or-configure-systemd-services

Comment: Well what if one wants to automate this configuration?

Comment: Remember, you will need to restart the snapd service before these changes take effect.

Comment: The method you posted here also doesn't work with authentication. Snap should just use the normal $http_proxy and $https_proxy env vars like everyone else. [Here is the ubuntu bug tracker link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1579652) for this problem.

Comment: @Teque5 did you get it working somehow?

Comment: @PauloPedroso Haha yes but mostly no. I manually downloaded the snap, extracted the contents since snap wouldn't let me install, mounted the squashfs that was inside, then ran once OK. After that I deleted the whole thing and swore off snaps forever; [Flatpaks](https://flatpak.org/) or docker images are a jillion times better.

Comment: @Teque5 I am out of Skype because of this. I don't believe I have the skills to do that in Skype. I have cursed snap last year because my linux install had problems and snapd wouldn't run.

Comment: Teque, Paulo, snapd *does* use the default environment variables. I don't know what you're saying doesn't work.

Comment: This method does not work in 20.04/snap2.45.3.1

Answer (score 16):

There is another way to add environment variables to systemd services:

Create a folder for the snap daemon and create configuration files for the environment variables:

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/snapd.service.d/
$ echo -e '[Service]\nEnvironment="http_proxy=http://1.2.3.4:3128/"' \
      | sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/snapd.service.d/http-proxy.conf
$ echo -e '[Service]\nEnvironment="https_proxy=http://1.2.3.4:3128/"' \
      | sudo tee /etc/systemd/system/snapd.service.d/https-proxy.conf
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl restart snapd
```

After that you can check if the environment variables are set for `snapd`:

```
$ systemctl show snapd | grep proxy
  Environment=http_proxy=http://1.2.3.4:3128/ https_proxy=http://1.2.3.4:3128/
  DropInPaths=/etc/systemd/system/snapd.service.d/http-proxy.conf /etc/systemd/system/snapd.service.d/https-proxy.conf
```

Answer (score 9):

Snap uses `snapd` daemon. You only need to define `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` in `/etc/environment` and restart the service: `systemctl restart snapd`.

Comment: But remember if you add the proxy variables to the /etc/environment file, every other application will have this as their default environment as well

Answer (score 3):

Snap service is configured to use special environment file, so you can just add http_proxy variable to it if your current environment variables are not picked up by the snap.

Open file:

```
sudo vim /etc/sysconfig/snapd
```

Add:

```
http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128
https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128
```

Comment: There is no `sysconfig` folder on Ubuntu.

Comment: This is not ubuntu config.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, because the snapd reads the /etc/environment file instead of get the ENV variable.
This example below doesn't work:

```
export https_proxy=http://<your.ip.here>:3128
```

you have to use:

```
http://<your.ip.here>:3128
```