# Unable to configure proxy settings in /etc/environment - file is read-only

Tags: permissions, environment-variables, snap, ubuntu-core

I'm trying to get Ubuntu Core 16 to [use a proxy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764610) to talk to the snap store.

When attempting to edit `/etc/environment`, I'm unable to save my change, due to it being read-only.

(The file permissions are 644, the problem seems to be `/dev/loop0 on / type squashfs (ro,relatime)`)

(Editing as root, from a `sudo -i` session)

core snap version:

```
Name              Version          Rev   Developer  Notes
core              16-2             1577  canonical  -
```

Initial `snap version`:

```
$ snap version
snap    2.23.6
snapd   2.23.6
series  16
kernel  4.4.0-77-generic
```

(snapd >= 2.28 supports setting proxy settings with `snap set core proxy.http` (insert relevant protocol there))

Comment: (Other things tried include finding the file on /writable, but that also fails...) (A device on a newer core snap version seems not to have the issue, but I'm trying to get the update to that version working over a proxy)

Comment: The problem is gone once it is updated, but my goal is to document the process of updating over a proxy.

Comment: Are you trying to edit it with a normal user? in /etc the file arre owned by root. 6 is only for root user other is 4 (that mean only read)

Comment: ls -l /etc/environment 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 96 avril 12  2017 /etc/environment

Comment: @PascalFares: "(Editing as root, from a sudo -i session)"

Comment: (It is Ubuntu Core, which has a read-only squashfs root filesystem, with all kinds of tricks (bind mounts, symlinks) to get some files writable...)