# Why Ubuntu software center is not showing some existing applications?

Tags: 18.04, software-center, android-studio

I had a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

I did upgrade, update. I had an active internet connection. I searched for Android studio and got the following result.

[image]

What is the **issue of not showing in the list**?

Comment: You can download it from developer.android.com/studio.

Comment: @guiverc No, I want to know the issue behind its absence in the list.

Comment: Open terminal and let us know the output `snap search android-studio`

Comment: @Kulfy

**error: Get**
       https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/search?confinement=strict%2Cclassic&fields=anon_download_url%2Carchitecture%2Cchannel%2Cdownload_sha3_384%2Csummary%2Cdescription%2Cbinary_filesize%2Cdownload_url%2Cepoch%2Cicon_url%2Clast_updated%2Cpackage_name%2Cprices%2Cpublisher%2Cratings_average%2Crevision%2Cscreenshot_urls%2Csnap_id%2Clicense%2Cbase%2Csupport_url%2Ccontact%2Ctitle%2Ccontent%2Cversion%2Corigin%2Cdeveloper_id%2Cdeveloper_name%2Cdeveloper_validation%2Cprivate%2Cconfinement%2Ccommon_ids&q=android-studio&scope=wide:
       proxyconnect tcp: EOF

Comment: The Android Studio is provided by Snap. So you are having problems with the same. Try `sudo systemctl restart snapd.service` and then search again with the command provided in previous comment.

Comment: I did it now and restarted, but still not showing.

Comment: What do you get after `snap refresh snapd`?

Comment: error: cannot refresh "snapd": cannot refresh snap-declaration for
       "gnome-logs": Get
       https://api.snapcraft.io/api/v1/snaps/assertions/snap-declaration/16/kIMfmZTJspWa8vtfbgU3W9Nbv4V5Qgmh?max-format=2:
       proxyconnect tcp: EOF

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82782/discussion-between-kulfy-and-hanugm).

Comment: You might want to make sure that the `gnome-software-plugin-snap` is installed so that the software center shows snap apps.  `sudo apt install gnome-software-plugin-snap`

Comment: gnome-software-plugin-snap is already the newest version (3.28.1-0ubuntu4.18.04.3).

Comment: @Terrance Yeah, I am using proxy.

Comment: Maybe https://askubuntu.com/questions/764610/how-to-install-snap-packages-behind-web-proxy-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 0):

Not all packages are available in the Ubuntu Software Center.

If you don't found Android Studio in the Software Center, you can found it on the official Website : https://developer.android.com/studio/install

I hope that will help you!

Comment: In general it is available.

Comment: I never found it personally.

Comment: @DevHugo I have observed that Android Studio is available in store via Snap and yes it is the latest stable version, i.e. 3.1.4.0. Search it again. Its always fun to learn new things. :-)