# snap daemon proxy with authentication

Tags: networking, proxy, snap

I'm having trouble getting snap to use a proxy with authentication.
I've tried configuring the `snapd.service` to setup the environment (http_proxy/https_proxy) and also used `/etc/environment` to do the same, as was suggested in these threads:

[How to install snap packages behind web proxy on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764610/how-to-install-snap-packages-behind-web-proxy-on-ubuntu-16-04)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1579652

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/K8VncJv4vp/

It connects to the proxy but does not use the credentials specified in the URL

```
http://username:password@proxyURL:port
```

Has anyone gotten around this?

Answer (score 3):

I've been stuck in the same situation but I've solved it.

1. Set your proxy in /etc/envirnment (or export http_porxy="http://username:password@proxyURL:port")
2. Check it with bash echo $http_proxy
3. sudo snap set system proxy.http=$http_proxy
4. sudo snap set system proxy.https=$http_proxy

With that configuration I could pass the proxy with authentification.

Answer (score -1):

Snap service is configured to use special environment file, so you can just add http_proxy variable to it if your current environment variables are not picked up by the snap.

Open file:

```
sudo vim /etc/sysconfig/snapd
```

Add:

```
http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128
https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128
```

https://askubuntu.com/a/1110040/757551