# getty/mingetty automatic login 16.04

Tags: 16.04, systemd, hostname

I have an nfsroot created from 14.04 that I am rebuilding using 16.04.  My nfsroot is shared by three systems named pc1,pc2 and pc3.  There are 3 matching user accounts named pc1, pc2, and pc3 as well.

When these systems boot up they automatically log in and subsequently run a bash login script.

In 14.04 I replaced mingetty in my upstart tty1.conf file as follows:

```
# tty1 - getty
#
# This service maintains a getty on tty1 from the point the system is
# started until it is shut down again.

start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=[2345] and (
        not-container or
        container CONTAINER=lxc or
        container CONTAINER=lxc-libvirt)

stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
#exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
script
    exec /sbin/mingetty --autologin `cat /proc/sys/kernel/hostname` --noclear tty1
end script
```

This worked just fine in 14.04 for my purposes.  It gleans the hostname from /proc and then uses that as the login name.

What I am trying to do is replicate the same behaviour in 16.04, but now using systemd.To do so I modified /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants.  Specifically I changed the ExecStart:

```
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -a $HOSTNAME --noclear %I $TERM
```

However from reading the systemd docs and using some google-fu I have leared that I cannot use backticks or environment variable substitution in the ExecStart line.  I have tested hard coding a user account instead and it works correctly, but I can't figure out how to do the same thing I was doing previously with upstart in systemd.

I've also tried using a small script for this purpose as well by changing the ExecStart line to:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/autogetty.sh"
```

The autogetty.sh script is simple script which cats to get the hostname and feeds it to mingetty.  It however doesn't appear to work.  I think the issue may be that for the service, the type is idle and from my researching online it needs to be fork.  I have yet to try modifying the service type yet.

I would like to know the "right way" to do this.  So far I'm just trying things to make it work, and even if I make it work I won't be sure if its the best way of doing it.

Thanks.

Comment: Well , since you cannot use environment variables in a `systemd` service, why not call a script instead ? Those can use environment variables, right ?

Comment: Added additional information about my attempts to use a script.

Answer (score 0):

### Wrong ideas and errors

> *I have leared that I cannot use backticks or environment variable substitution in the `ExecStart` line.*

You have learned a falsehood.  The doco does not in fact say this.  You *can* use environment variable substitution (with a syntax that is subtly different to most Unix shells').  It is simply the case that *there is no `HOSTNAME` environment variable to substitute*.  Service processes are not spawned with such an environment variable set up.

Unit files are parameterizable, and the `%H` parameter expands to the (dynamic) host name as it was at the point in the past that the unit was loaded from file.

> ```
> ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/autogetty.sh"
> ```
>
> […] *I have yet to try modifying the service type yet.*

Good.  Do not.  That's the wrong thing to do.  Only change the readiness notification protocol to `forking` if your service actually implements that protocol.  Don't do it as a kludge because you have erroneously made a program that forks for no good reason.

Because that's exactly what you have done.  The unnecessary `/bin/sh` is forking a child to run `autogetty.sh`, which ends up being a second shell process running that shell script.  The second shell process is then forking to run `mingetty` as a grandchild.  This does not match the forking readiness protocol anyway, as that relies upon fork *followed by exit in the parent*.

Take a lesson from the world of daemontools:  Services are run, not spawned.  The program that you run as `ExecStart` should *be* the service process, not something that *spawns* the service process.

### The right way

The right way to set things up is this:

- Override a specific instance of the template, for the specific terminal device, not the whole template.
- Use `%H` to obtain the host name in `ExecStart`.  Or use `%m` and the machine ID as your user account names.
- Invoke things properly:

  - Just run `agetty` directly, for best results.  You don't actually need any scripting for the task as described at all.
  - If you do nonetheless choose to insert a superfluous wrapper script:

    - Don't use `/bin/sh -c scriptfile`.  Just make `scriptfile` executable, with a properly specified script interpreter, and run it directly.
    - Make sure that your script uses `exec` to become the dæmon getty process.

### Further reading

- Werner Fink and Karel Zak. [`agetty`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/en/man8/agetty.8.html).  Ubuntu 15.04 manual pages.
- https://askubuntu.com/a/659268/43344
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233855/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194218/5132
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). [*Readiness protocol problems with Unix dæmons*](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/unix-daemon-readiness-protocol-problems.html). Frequently Given Answers.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200365/5132
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194653/5132