# How to create ubuntu server 16.04 autologin?

Tags: systemd, tty

Something has changed in server 16.04 LTS, I can't find tty1, but I need to make an auto-login on tty1 (in console mode), in 14.04 LTS I can make this work.

I can't find `/etc/init/tty1.conf`

How to, or a link?

Comment: I have the `/etc/init/tty[1-6].conf` after an upgrade from 14.04... Did you do a fresh install? I could be that you somehow switched to full X11 (graphical) only mode.

Comment: See this for classic `inittab` login: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/299408/how-to-login-automatically-without-typing-the-root-username-or-password-in-build/300152#300152

Answer (score 11):

In Ubuntu 16.04, which uses `systemd`, the method is slightly different. I'll quote the relevant bits of my related post [How do I override or configure systemd services?](https://askubuntu.com/q/659267/158442):

> Say I want to have TTY2 autologin to my user (this is not advisable,
>   but just an example). TTY2 is run by the `getty@tty2` service (`tty2`
>   being an instance of the template
>   `/lib/systemd/system/getty@service`). To do this, I have to modify the
>   `getty@tty2` service.
>
> […]
>
> In particular, I have to change the `ExecStart` line, which currently
>   is:
>
> ```
> $ systemctl cat getty@tty2 | grep Exec     
> ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear %I $TERM
> ```
>
> To override this, do:
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl edit getty@tty2
> ```
>
> And add:
>
> ```
> [Service]
> ExecStart=
> ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -a <USERNAME> --noclear %I $TERM
> ```
>
> […]
>
> Now:
>
> ```
> $ systemctl cat getty@tty2 | grep Exec
> ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear %I $TERM
> ExecStart=
> ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -a <USERNAME> --noclear %I $TERM
> ```
>
> And if I do:
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl restart getty@tty2
> ```
>
> and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>, presto! I'll be
>   logged into my account on that TTY.

Comment: That procedure brings to me a blank tty screen.

Comment: @Zac and what does `systemctl status getty@tty2` report for you?

Comment: I was in a virtual machine with just 1 tty, and I was not able to log in anymore! (blessed snapshots!) I solved as I wrote [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/289612/44112).

Comment: @Zac if you says so. This works fine for me on Arch Linux and Ubuntu.

Comment: I followed your guide and my machine can log in automatically now. BUT I cannot ssh to the machine as possible before. Please help me to get back to my SSH connection.

Comment: @NamGVU since the guide doesn't touch SSH settings at all, the cause must be elsewhere. Does reverting the changes given here fix SSH?

Comment: Is there any way to automate this using a script?

Comment: @VarunAgw sure, create `/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty2.service.d/override.conf` with the additional lines, and run `systemctl daemon-reload`.

Comment: For some reason, tty2 doesn't auto login at reboot while tty1 does. `who -u` shows only tty1 after login

Comment: @VarunAgw even after you switch to tty2?

Comment: @muru I can't switch using Ctrl+Alt+F2. I have develop a program which use ttyecho to launch a program in tty2 and then take regular screenshots using fbgrab

Comment: How to revert these changes?

Comment: @Orient delete the override file in `/etc/systemd/system/getty*.service.d`

Comment: @muru Can I just edit `/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service` instead of `systemctl edit getty@tty1`?

Comment: @Orient the usual method to manually do this is to create .conf files `/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty2.service.d/` and run `systemctl daemon-reload`. I'm not so sure of using other directories.

Answer (score -2):

I used this website to achieve auto-login: http://www.pcworld.com/article/259236/how_to_turn_your_laptop_into_a_typewriter.html.

```
sudo nano /etc/init/tty1.conf
```

Again, type your password if requested. You are now editing a
configuration file, the last line of which starts with an 'exec'
command. Replace that line with:

```
exec /bin/login -f USERNAME < /dev/tty1 > /dev/tty1 2>&1
```

Where USERNAME is your own username, of course. Be sure to type this
line accurately. Then save the file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>) and exit (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>).

Now, let's test again to make sure everything is working correctly. Reboot the computer to see if automatic login works:

```
sudo reboot now
```

Comment: This answer won' t work for 16.04 because it uses systemd by default and not upstart. Even for upstart systems, you should use `agetty`'s `-a` option instead of this.

Comment: That's strange, as I was pretty sure I was running 16.04 Server. That would't change just because I was using a PPC, would it?