# How can I get autologin at startup working on Ubuntu Server 16.04.1?

Tags: command-line, login, startup

I have a problem with autologin at startup in Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 LTS.

I use this server only for listening internet radio so I do not care about security.

I was able to create a bash script to auto start mplayer but can't configure autologin.

I've tried at least 4 solutions (always editing the file `/etc/init/tty1.conf` and of course replacing USERNAME with actual user name):

1. change the line from

   ```
   exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
   ```

   to

   ```
   exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1 -a USERNAME
   ```
2. change the line from

   ```
   exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
   ```

   to

   ```
   exec /bin/login -f USERNAME < /dev/tty1 > /dev/tty1 2>&1
   ```
3. Install `rungetty`, comment the line

   ```
   exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
   ```

   and add the line

   ```
   exec /sbin/rungetty --autologin USERNAME tty1
   ```
4. Install `mingetty`, comment the line

   ```
   exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
   ```

   and add the line

   ```
   exec /sbin/mingetty --autologin USERNAME tty1
   ```

Nothing helps - I have to input my login and password at startup - any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo systemctl edit getty@tty1.service
```

This will the create a [drop-in](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) file (if neccessary) and open it an editor. Add the following, **replacing `myusername` with your user name**:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noissue --autologin myusername %I $TERM
Type=idle
```

This will:

- Create the folder `/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d` if necessary
- Create the file `/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf` if necessary

Comment: I followed your guide and my machine can log in automatically now. BUT I cannot ssh to the machine as possible before. Please help me to get back to my SSH connection.

Comment: Hi Nam. Your user have a password? I tried this in a machine and i can access to it over SSH with the user passwd. Shows any error? Thanks.

Comment: Too long ago and the machine is deleted on my side; sorry I can't get you the error. User has a password of course.

Comment: Your guide took me stuck at `[OK] Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.` during boot

Comment: Instead of manually creating the `.d` directory and the `override.conf` file we can also simply say `sudo systemctl edit getty@tty1.service`. It will the create the file (if neccessary) and open it an editor. Simply _save_ the file under the suggested name when finished.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my autologin is also working now. May I know do you have anyway to wait for 10sec before autologin so that anyone can interrupt autologin between that period and login manually with different user.

Comment: Still works in 20.04.  @PerlDuck I've edited the solution with a request that your improved steps are added to the original solution, they're faster, use the official `systemctl` tool which is less prone to error and chooses a text editor automatically, alleviating doubt.  I've preserved the OP's documentation about the files that it creates so it doesn't lose informational value. Thanks kindly!

Comment: @tresf Very nice, thank you. I took the freedom to replace _"This will the create the file"_ with _"This will the create a [drop-in](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) file"_ so that people know what kind of file that is -- and what to search for in case more information is needed.

Comment: Doesn't work in 20.04. (as appears to be the standard for Ubuntu questions.) Rebooting the machine after these steps, I ran "who", and the user was not logged in.

Comment: Doesn't work on 18.04. I just get a black screen with blinking cursor...

Comment: Worked like a charm in ubuntu server 20.04.2 fresh install. Ran `sudo systemctl edit getty@tty1.service` and added the file contents then rebooted. On reboot, the user had logged in.

Answer (score 6):

agetty opens a tty port, prompts for a login name and invokes the `/bin/login` command.

This file overrides the config by default of agetty on systemd for tty1. This provides a new instance of tty1 with autologin for the user specified.

By the way, the parameter `--noissue` is used to hide the contents of `/etc/issue` on login, so not needed in your case.

The option `Type=idle` found in the default `getty@.service` will delay the service startup until all jobs are completed in order to avoid polluting the login prompt with boot-up messages. When starting X automatically, it may be useful to start `getty@tty1.service` immediately by adding `Type=simple` into the file.

More info: [getty: Archlinux.org](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Getty#Automatic_login_to_virtual_console)

Comment: Once again - thank you very much for explanations - they are very deep and clear.  Some more information about autologin here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/771837/how-to-create-ubuntu-server-16-04-autologin and about overriding here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/659267/how-do-i-override-or-configure-systemd-services