# How to auto login to Ubuntu Server after installation using preseed file

Tags: server, 18.04, auto-login

I am flashing ubuntu server on system through automation i.e. which includes preseed file.
I need to autologin user once ubuntu server is installed.

I have tried approach mentioned in this link https://askubuntu.com/a/819154/863211. It works if I enter manually but the same is not working when I add commands in preseed file.

I expect to autologin user once ubuntu server installation finishes using preseed file

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by adding script which contains the same logic as mentioned in above link. This script is then called in preseed file.