# How can I create a user who can log in without a password (delete password in passwd command?) in 18.04.4 over ssh?

Tags: command-line, permissions, password, users

This is an absolutely new machine and my current situation is I don't have root's password. I have a user (A) that has sudo privilege. I would like to create a user (B) which needs no password to log in. And I can only manipulate the machine through ssh.

```
$ whoami
A
$ sudo adduser -m B
$ sudo passwd -d B
passwd: password expiry information changed.
$ su - B
Password:
su: Authentication failure
$ sudo su - B
$ whoami
B
$ passwd -d B
passwd: Permission denied.
```

The above shows I cannot delete the password.

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you successfully deleted B's password on your first try (`sudo passwd -d B`).

However, you're on the wrong track: Deleting a password prevents login under any circumstances; it does NOT enable autologin. Undo the damage by creating a new password for B.

- How to enable autologin on a server (no GUI): [How can I get autologin at startup working on Ubuntu Server 16.04.1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819117/how-can-i-get-autologin-at-startup-working-on-ubuntu-server-16-04-1/819154)
- How to enable autologin on a Desktop (with GUI): Edit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf.