# How to set automatic login in tty1?

Tags: tty, auto-login

I want the automatic login after pressing Ctrl-Alt-F1 in GUI. I tried to change the last line of /etc/init/tty1.conf to

```
exec /sbin/getty --autologin USERNAME -8 38400 tty1
```

but it did not work. My OS is Ubuntu 16.10

I have set the automatic login in tty2 by following [muru's guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771837/how-to-create-ubuntu-server-16-04-autologin).

Comment: Did you restart the tty1 service after editing the file ?

Comment: @Serg How to restart the tty service? I just rebooted the computer.

Comment: @tmpbin see the link muru provided. It explains everything quite nicely