# Auto login as root in embedded Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, login, root, auto-login

Upon system start, how can I make the terminal to auto log in root without asking for a login and a password?

I've already tried:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45552/login-automatically-as-root-at-startup
[How to create ubuntu server 16.04 autologin?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771837/how-to-create-ubuntu-server-16-04-autologin?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

**Why?**
This is Ubuntu running on an embedded system (ARM processor) that I use to develop a device.
I connect the dev. board to the PC via USB which creates serial port that I use as a terminal (command-line).

**Security**
Yep, I know it's a bad idea generally. But I develop an isolated device that I need to restart very often. I want auto log for the sake of development ease.