# Why is /etc/init/tty?.conf ignored in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, upstart, systemd, tty, virtual-console

When using Ubuntu 14.04, I used to have a custom `/etc/init/tty2.conf` that started a program in this virtual terminal. But after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04, these files seem to be ignored. Regardless of my modifications, virtual terminal ends up running getty after boot.

I understand that Ubuntu 16.04 includes a `systemd` side by side with `upstart` subsystem. But since `/etc/init/tty?.conf` files are present by default in an installed system, I'd expect them to be respected.

Should I enable some systemd service to restore old behaviour (like it is done for `/etc/rc.local`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that Ubuntu 16.04 includes a systemd side by side with
>   upstart subsystem.

The only role of Upstart in a default 16.04 is for *user* sessions. It has nothing to do with system init, which is entirely handled by systemd. It might be possible to force Upstart to be `init`, but it is not supported.

The `/etc/init/*.conf` are therefore ignored (and are probably just residual files). If you want to configure TTY2, you'll have to edit systemd services. See my posts in [How to create ubuntu server 16.04 autologin?](https://askubuntu.com/q/771837/158442) and [How do I override or configure systemd services?](https://askubuntu.com/q/659267/158442)

Comment: so is the presence of `/etc/init/*.conf` files a bug since they are silently ignored?

Comment: @Dmitriusan meh, nope. You'll find that many packages provide at least two out of (systemd, upstart, sysv) init files, and that means one of them gets ignored anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to instructions at accepted answer, accomplished my target with `/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty2.service.d/override.conf`

```
[Unit]
Description=Vim for notes on %I

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target


[Service]
User=my_user
Group=my_group
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/bin/bash -lc '/usr/bin/vim /media/notes/note_`LC_ALL=us_US.utf8 /bin/date "+%%b%%g"`'
StandardInput=tty-force
StandardOutput=inherit
StandardError=inherit
```

Caveats:

- had to escape `%` as `%%`, otherwise they have been replaced by systemd variables
- did not get input/output streams without `Standard*` statements at `[Service]`