# Automatically login on ubuntu server, but not in a tty?

Tags: server, auto-login

I would like to have my user automatically log in on ubuntu server (so that various "on login" services start), but I do *not* want that [user to be authenticated in one of the various available ttys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771837/how-to-create-ubuntu-server-16-04-autologin).  Is it possible to have my user log in without exposing a terminal to someone with access to the keyboard?

Comment: This seems like a workaround. It might match your actual usage better to change your "on login" service triggers to something else. My server's services are either at-startup, on-demand, or scheduled. None of mine are upon login. Alternately, why do you need to keep a terminal window open? Start the service using systemd, logout, and close the window.

Comment: "why do you need to keep a terminal window open?" this is specifically what I want *not* to happen.

Comment: @user535733, the "on login" things are ubuntu things, not mine.  One example is the network manager that only starts on login.

Comment: Does this help? https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/lockdown-command-line.html.en

Comment: Ah, so you seem to be serving from an Ubuntu Desktop, not Ubuntu Server. Seems unnecessarily complicated to do it that way, but I'm sure you have your reasons. Real Ubuntu Server lacks both a Desktop Environment and Network Manager, and has no "on login" things at all. On my network, I would simply move the server into an LXD container that can run in the background on any Ubuntu system (though I have dedicated hardware for my containers - each service in it's own container).

Comment: @user535733 ah.  I already had ubuntu desktop installed, and figured I'd just disable lightdm and it would turn magically into ubuntu server.  I suppose that was incorrect.  :)

Comment: Do you want a remote Desktop? Or a remote (headless) Server? To convert one into the other is simply a matter of adding and removing packages. However, it's easier to reinstall when converting from Desktop to Server. The base package set is identical, but removing the Desktop packages is (deliberately) difficult for several (good) reasons.