# Auto login on boot Ubuntu 18.04.3 server

Tags: 18.04, server, login, auto-login

I am trying to configure a Ubuntu server to automatically log in on boot.

I have tried to edit the `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` file, but that did not allow me to autologin.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/819154/197910 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/771837/how-to-create-ubuntu-server-16-04-autologin/776197