# Server 18.04 auto log on

Tags: 18.04, server

I am running ubuntu 18.04 on a raspberry pi 3. I'd like to have it when I turn the unit on, it would automatically login to a given user. I have tried the following method layed out in the following question: [How can I get autologin at startup working on Ubuntu Server 16.04.1?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819117/how-can-i-get-autologin-at-startup-working-on-ubuntu-server-16-04-1)

Perhaps I don't understand it. Would someone be willing to explain to me how this is accomplished?

Comment: Are you using a desktop environment or cli

Comment: cli. ubuntu server only has cli available.

Comment: Do you merely need to start some job or application? You don't need to be logged in to do that.

Comment: I'd simply like to not have the step of logging into the box when it is powered on.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing this question [How to create ubuntu server 16.04 autologin?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771837/how-to-create-ubuntu-server-16-04-autologin)

In a vm this was my procedure

```
sudo systemctl edit getty@tty1
```

And add:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -a <USERNAME> --noclear %I $TERM
```

Replace `<USERNAME>` of course with your username.

save and exit. Reboot

This was just tested on a VM running Ubuntu Server 18.04(not raspberry pi however)

It was a successful autologin

I do not claim this to be secure in anyway!
For testing purpose only.