# Auto login on tty4 or tty5

Tags: 20.04, lts

I'm not talking about auto login to the GUI.

I need to auto login a user on tty4 or tty5

Does someone have a procedure to doing that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create ubuntu server 16.04 autologin?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771837/how-to-create-ubuntu-server-16-04-autologin)

Answer (score 1):

These commands will configure a server to autologin the `root` user on `tty4`.

```
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty4.service.d
cat <<EOF > /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty4.service.d/autologin.conf
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear -n --autologin root %I $TERM
EOF
```

Hopefully it is obvious how to change the user or `tty`.

**notes**

I am stealing [the configuration](https://git.launchpad.net/livecd-rootfs/tree/live-build/ubuntu-server/includes.chroot.ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer/usr/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service.d/autologin.conf?id=a81bea1f0c0d2df583b8666f7367bfac591c7321) from the live-server image which will autologin the `ubuntu-server` user on any `tty`.

I tested this on Ubuntu 22.04.