# How to disable cconsole output after automatically logging in user (Ubtuntu Server 22.02 LTS)

Tags: server, 22.04, auto-login

i just set up Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS on an old Laptop of mine.

Before you ask in terms of security concerns: This is for personal use only, there is no enterprise / productive enviroment involved.

Also good to know before eventually judging: I just searched the web for ~ 2 hours for a solution, didn't find anything helpful. And i am an absolute beginner with Linux.

I managed to get my user automatically logged in via this solution:

- Creating a directory:

`sudo mkdir /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d`

- Create and open file:

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf`

- Input into the newly created file:

`[Service] ExecStart= ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noissue --autologin username %I $TERM Type=idle`

So this is working just fine, but there is a text output after successfully logging in automatically:

`server login: user (automatic login)`

followed by MOTD.

My question is: How can i disable / edit this text (before the MOTD)?

I would like it to not be there.

Also if there is another way to enable automatic login (maybe without even any oputput at standard settings) please let me know, i will be glad to use this instead then.

Thank you in advance!
Greetings and best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Add the `--skip-login` argument to your `agetty` command.

**see also**

- [Auto login on tty4 or tty5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410997/auto-login-on-tty4-or-tty5/)
- http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/agetty.8.html

**notes**

I tested this on Ubuntu 22.04