# Does dist-upgrade replace service files?

Tags: 18.04, systemd, docker

I recently noticed a server performing `apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade`

Amongst other things, docker was updated and restarted.

However, I noticed some changes I made to the service file previously were now gone. The file at `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` seems to have been reset.

Is this possible? I don't recall if I ran `daemon-reload` after these changes.

EDIT: To be clear: I'm wondering is `dist-upgrade` basically removed the service file and replaced it with a default one?

And does `daemon-reload` prevent this in the future?

EDIT2: Ok, looks like `sudo systemctl edit docker.service` is the way to go and performs a `daemon-reload` on save.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I override or configure systemd services?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/659267/how-do-i-override-or-configure-systemd-services)

Comment: @muru No, my question is more "did dist-upgrade forcibly replace the entire service file with a new one, ignoring the existing one?"

Comment: @muru Ah, I read a bit further and it does detail not to edit /lib/systemd/ files. Yeah this is going to be it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't edit files in /lib/systemd/ or /usr/share/systemd as they will get overwritten on updates.

Instead, copy the file to /etc/systemd/ and make the changes there.

The /etc/ directory (at least for systemd) is considered the place to store local config files.  All other /**/systemd/ directories are considered sources of default and sample config files that should be replaced on any upgrade.

Another reason to not edit these package supplied config files is that if you copy it to /etc/systemd/... and edit it and make a mistake, you can always compare with the original file.

`systemctl daemon-reload` doesn't prevent anything.  It just tells systemd to re-examine all of its config and use whatever has changed.

Comment: think `/usr/local/lib/systemd/system/` is better than `/etc/systemd...` [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224992/where-do-i-put-my-systemd-unit-file)

Comment: @bac0n the systemd-sanctioned location is `/etc/systemd`. That’s what `systemctl edit` uses.

Comment: I wouldn't edit the one in /usr/local/lib/systemd either, I'd copy that to /etc/systemd as well before editing.

Comment: @StephenKitt, what you [suggest](https://steveazz.xyz/micro/systemd-drop-in/) is something completely different and deserves its own answer and even be the preferred one, still, I think, copying files to `/etc/systemd/` is not recommended, e.g., you lose the ability to *mask* units.

Comment: @bac0n: Actually, you're wrong.  You mask units *by* putting a blank file in /etc/systemd/ basically by replacing the system default with a blank file.  If you are putting a real (non-empty) file there anyway, you can disable the unit instead of masking it.

Comment: but where do you put the edited file?

Comment: The edited file goes in /etc/systemd/system.   This masks the default with a replacement file.  If you want to disable the unit temporarily, you can just disable it, no need to mask.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126878/discussion-between-user10489-and-bac0n).

Comment: @bac0n it’s already covered in [muru’s answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/659268/412264), no point in duplicating it IMO ;-).