# check_apt issue with Nagios

Tags: 22.04, nagios3, nrpe

Running a base install of Ubuntu 22.04 using Nagios and NRPE to monitor hosts, all running 22.04. My issue is with check_apt returning two different results:

```
$# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_apt
 APT OK: 0 packages available for upgrade (0 critical updates). |available_upgrades=0;;;0 critical_updates=0;;;0

$# /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H 127.0.0.1 -c check_apt 
APT WARNING: 9 packages available for upgrade (0 critical updates). |available_upgrades=9;;;0 critical_updates=0;;;0
```

One reports 0 packages, the other 9 even though they are the same server. Having checked in depth there are no updates

Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: My guess would be that they’re running as different users. For example, you may be running the test as root but nrpe runs it as the nagios user, and potentially causing the plug-in to malfunction. Try running the plug-in as user nagios to make sure.

Comment: yep ive checked that, confirmed same if using root or Nagios

Comment: In that case the only thing I can think of is that the definition of the `check_apt` command in the `nrpe.cfg` is not actually exactly as you run it yourself. Please include the definition in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to `PrivateTmp=true`
in `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/nagios-nrpe-server.service`.

[Overriding](https://askubuntu.com/questions/659267/how-do-i-override-or-configure-systemd-services) this to  `PrivateTmp=false`, then reloading `systemd` config and `nagios-nrpe-server.service` fixed the issue for me.

Note : somewhat similar to [this issue with check_disk via nrpe](https://serverfault.com/questions/940140/systemd-privatetmp-true-security-implications)

Answer (score 0):

You could find out the packages list with `-l` option in the `check_apt` command of NRPE. Also can check with `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

My `apt-get dist-upgrade` returns:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

Same result with the `-l` option in the `check_apt` command.

Work around solution is excluding the packages in the `check_apt` command with `--exclude=REGEXP` option.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  I've fixed the formatting on your post, but for future reference, Ask Ubuntu uses the same Markdown that you are used to (from your account and answers) on Stack Overflow.