# Gitea snap service file replaced

Tags: snap, systemd

I installed gitea with snap on Ubuntu some weeks ago.

Yesterday the service stopped to work and after digging into to logs I found that systemd service file had beed changed.

The file is:

```
/etc/systemd/system/snap.gitea.web.service
```

I had previously modified it adding

```
[Service]
User=gitea
Group=gitea
```

but yesterday these modifications disappeared.

What can be the cause? Who can help me?

Comment: In all likelihood, snapd replaced it when it updated the snap? You should use override files instead of modifying the unit file directly

Comment: how can I do that? override file (1) or modifying the unit (2) ?

Comment: You already tried (2) as you mentioned in the question. For (1) use `systemctl edit snap.gitea.web.service` and add your modifications to the override file. See https://askubuntu.com/a/659268/158442

Comment: Tnx! Just to know, where the unit files are stored?